# Automated Importing of Landsat with new USGS MLT metadata file

Tags: metadata, landsat

Has anyone had any luck importing Landsat with the updated MLT files?

Besides ENVI 5 SP1 I see no software that can create images from these new files.

I can do a manual layer stack but then the band data is not embedded in the header and so I can't pan sharpen and manually updating the headers is a pain when I'm trying to import several dozen files.

Comment: Have you tried GRASS?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have Envi 4.8 but the problem is when I try to open Metadata file from Landsat... Please help us.

Answer (score -1):

In ENVI, you can just add the wavelength metadata back to the header after stacking.

Comment: While this answer could potentially be right, please add more details to it, so that someone can actually use it.